# tf.functon in tensorflow with a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train a model using TensorFlow. There is a bottleneck in my code, which make my Tensor flow optimization to crash. I found out that this most likely is relating to a part in my code where I have a loop:

here is a minimum working example:

```
import numpy  as np 
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.optimize 

kon = 0.01
mu  = 1.5
fi  = 0.5 
kappa = 22
w = (1-theta)

n =100
xs = tf.random.normal(shape=(n,), stddev=0.2)
eps = tf.random.normal(shape=(n,), stddev=0.17)
z = tf.sigmoid(tf.random.normal(shape=(n,), stddev=0.22))




def my_function(z, eps, x0):
    def F(hi):
     return (mu/fi)*np.log(hi) -(1-mu)*kappa*(hi)**(1+(1/fi))-mu*(np.log(w*ei*xs)-np.log(kon))-np.log(ze)

    hvec = np.empty((0,))
    # leisure today

    for ze,ei,xs in zip(z, eps, x0):
        ei=np.exp(ei)
        xs=np.exp(xs)
        htemp = scipy.optimize.newton_krylov(F, 0.5)
        hvec = np.append(hvec, htemp)
    return hvec
```

if I use the `tf.function` to decorate my function I get this error.

```
@tf.function
def my_function(z, eps, x0):
    def F(hi):
     return (mu/fi)*np.log(hi) -(1-mu)*kappa*(hi)**(1+(1/fi))-mu*(np.log(w*ei*xs)-np.log(kon))-np.log(ze)

    hvec = np.empty((0,))
    # leisure today

    for ze,ei,xs in zip(z, eps, x0):
        ei=np.exp(ei)
        xs=np.exp(xs)
        htemp = scipy.optimize.newton_krylov(F, 0.5)
        hvec = np.append(hvec, htemp)
    return hvec


htest=my_function(z,eps,x0)
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in converted code:

   .....

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.
```

I tried to follow this route:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(None, tf.float32)]) 
def tf_function(input): 
  y = tf.numpy_function(my_function, [input], tf.float32) 
  return y
```

but the error message that I get once I call the `tf_function` is:

```
htestTF= tf_function(z,eps,x0)
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: When input_signature is provided, only pass arguments covered by it. Received 3 argument(s).
```

Can someone who has experience help me to debugg this?

Comment: Why even bother using the decorator if you're only using numpy functions?

Comment: @xdurch0 This is a function within a function and the optimization in TensorFlow fails because of the loop in the function I able I show. I am trying to decorate because that's what people in Tensflow seem to suggest for the type of error shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the `zip` function, which autograph doesn't currently transform: you need to use `for i in range(len(z))` and then `ze = z[i]`.

That said, your function uses only NumPy so it won't work as expected: tf.function requires TensorFlow code.

To train in TensorFlow, you would need to change all the `np.*` calls to their equivalent `tf.*`, replace `hvec` with `hvec = tf.TensorArray(...)`, and replace `scipy.optimize.newton_krylov` with a TF-based implementation.